# how to copy CSV data that is present in blob to azure storage table using logic app

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I designed a logic app to copy the data from blob to azure storage table using logic app
now, I m getting my output as wrong as all the data that is present in blob is shown in the output in single column of azure storage table .

I tried using get blob content action and then insert entity from azure storage table .in insert entity step I m getting as all the output of blob content is getting stored in single column of azure storage table

Answer (score 0):

Once content is retrieved from csv file you need to convert data into Json. Then using compose action you can insert data into table.
Reproduced issue from my side and below are the steps I followed,

1. Created logic app as shown below,

[image]

2. Created container in storage account and uploaded a CSV file in container.
   [image]

3.Next using compose action to split the contents of the CSV file on every new line into an array.
[image]

Here is the expression used in compose action:

```
split(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),decodeUriComponent('%0D%0A'))
```

4. Removing last(empty) line from previous output using another compose action as shown below,

[image]

```
take(outputs('Compose'),add(length(outputs('Compose')),-1))
```

5.Separating filed names using compose action
[image]

```
split(first(outputs('Compose')), ',')
```

6. Forming json as shown below using Select action,
   [image]

```
skip(outputs('Compose_3'), 1)
outputs('Compose_2')[0]  split(item(), ',')?[0]
outputs('Compose_2')[1]   split(item(), ',')?[1]
outputs('Compose_2')[2]   split(item(), ',')?[2]
outputs('Compose_2')[3]   split(item(), ',')?[3]
```

7. As there are multiple rows in csv file, using for each loop as shown below,
   [image]
8. Using compose action, forming json to insert data into azure table,
   [image]
9. Inserting data into table from output of Compose4 action,
   [image]
10. Logic app ran successfully and inserted data into azure table,
    [image]

Output of Get blob Content:
[image]

Output of Select:

[image]

Output of Insert entity:
[image]

Data inserted into table:
[image]